# How to check which MySQL-databases are still in use? #CleaningUp

Tags: mysql, database, verification, data-cleaning, usage-statistics

I am having a cleaning situation over here, the old programmer didn't clean up his out-of-use databases & users.
While some of the databases are still in use by external sites (on other ftp-servers), some are obsolete and just cluttering up the system.

> My question is: How can I figure out which databases (& users) are still in use by other websites? (**without checking every website** that has ever been created where ever this might be located)

I need to be sure that a MySQL database (& user) are not actively being used by any site anymore, so I can safely delete it to clean up the system.

*p.s.: It could also be that a database is still in use, but doesn't do any INSERTs or UPDATEs at all, but only SELECTs the data to load the website.*

*p.p.s.: I can't (temporary) deactivate/remove databases (& users), because this will cause clients to lose revenue, customers, search ranking etc. etc. and at the end will cost us/me.*

Comment: RoFLoL!! You funny :-P
No can't do.. doing those kind of things will costs clients to lose revenue and customers even search rankings, and at the end that will cost us/me

Comment: you can try last_update on a certain DB? that gives you some insight and maybe a look at the full process list?

Comment: As mentioned, it is not necessary to contain recently updated fields, it might just contain fields wich are created when building the website, and after that only being used for SELECTs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want even selects I think your options is general query log
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html
Enable it, parse it and get used dbs/tables

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.
To bad that the general query log was disabled.
But do you know how I can enable this by using PuTTy? (I can login as root) (I will also start up another question for this)

Comment: You ssh into server, change MySQL config and will need a server restart (as you didn't enable it before, just setting  ON or OFF won't be sufficient, you'll need to provide log path)

Comment: In what directory/file should I add this, and how/what do I add in it?

Comment: https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/ find conf file using this guide. then add `general_log_file = /path/to/query.log
general_log      = 1` to it

Comment: there is a new line before `general_log ` (comments don't allow new lines)